# Variable API Key for Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Once upon a time in a magical land you were able to set the API key of the old `MapView` by adding it in it's constructor. This was helpful as I could have something along the lines of:

```
mMapView = new MapView(getActivity(), Environment.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY);
```

This allowed me to have a key that could be changed based on whether the code was production or not (via swapping out `Environment` which contains a number of other lovely things).

Looking at the new Google maps API docs, code and related posts there doesn't seem to be a way to do this or something similar. I do have one idea of a workaround that requires me to make a `strings.xml` file to be read by the `AndroidManifest` that I also swap like I do `Environment` but I would much rather just one "configuration file" and not two.

**So my question:** Is there a way to set the API Key for these new maps in some way other than in the `AndroidManifest`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not.  However, the problem of different keys for production or not is solved in another way.  Through the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) you can associate as many signing key + package name pairs with the same API key as you want.  For instance, you can have your debugging and signing keys registered to the same Map API key, and they all use the same API key now.

Under the `Key for Android apps` in your console, click on the link in right side bar that says `Edit allowed Android apps...` and add both your keys (plus package name).

Comment: @cplain It does! I have my debug certs from two machines, plus release cert each for two different package names all tied to one key.  So much better than managing the v1 keys!

Comment: And what is the format of using multiple certificate fingerprints? `debugSha1;my.package prodSha1;my.package` or `debugSha1;my.package,prodSha1;my.package` or maybe any other format? I cound not find any documentation how to use multiple certificates.

Comment: @zmeda -- It is SHA;package.name with one entry per line. the documentation is in the pop up window when you add/manage keys.  Quoting it -- "One SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon) per line. Example: 45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example"